# Resize extended partition lvm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, fdisk, gparted

This is the disk schema I have which is coming from `lsblk` and `lvs`. What I want to do is resize `sda5` which is of type `Extended` to the size of the block device `/dev/sda` which is 100GB

```
   NAME             MAJ:MIN           RM      SIZE   RO    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT                              
sda              8:0               0       100G   0     disk                                            
|-sda1           8:1               0       243M   0     part    /boot                                   
|-sda2           8:2               0       1K     0     part                                            
`-sda5           8:5               0       49.8G  0     part                                            
|-osiris-root    254:0             0       45.8G  0     lvm     /                                       
`-osiris-swap_1  254:1             0       4G     0     lvm     [SWAP]                                  
sr0              11:0              1       1024M  0     rom                                             
LV               VG                Attr    LSize  Pool  Origin  Data%       Meta%  Move  Log  Cpy%Sync  Convert
root             osiris-wi-ao----  45.76g                                                               
swap_1           osiris-wi-ao----  4.00g
```

Is there any way to do it using `parted`, `fdisk` or any other tool? Thanks in advance.

`fdisk -l /dev/sda*` outputs

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x00082e2b

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type 
/dev/sda1 * 2048 499711 497664 243M 83 Linux 
/dev/sda2 501758 104855551 104353794 49.8G 5 Extended 
/dev/sda5 501760 104855551 104353792 49.8G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda1: 243 MiB, 254803968 bytes, 497664 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk /dev/sda2: 1 KiB, 1024 bytes, 2 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type 
/dev/sda2p1 2 104353793 104353792 49.8G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda5: 49.8 GiB, 53429141504 bytes, 104353792 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend your `sda5`, you need to extend its container too, `sda2`. Using command-line tools, the simplest way to do this is to use `sfdisk`:

```
sfdisk /dev/sda
```

This will print the current partition table, which should match what you saw in `fdisk`:

```
Disk image: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe59ec859

Old situation:

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
image1     *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
image2          501758 104855551 104353794 49.8G  5 Extended
image5          501760 104855551 104353792 49.8G 83 Linux

Type 'help' to get more information.
```

At the `>>>` prompt, start re-defining all your partitions:

```
2048,497664,83,*
```

(this is the first partition: start sector, length in sectors, type, and a `*` to make it bootable). `sfdisk` will respond with

```
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x03408377.
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 243 MiB.
      image1 :         2048       499711 (243M) Linux
```

and prompts for `image2` (`sda2`). Enter

```
501758,,5
```

which tells `sfdisk` to create an extended partition starting at sector 501758 and occupying all the available space after that; `sfdisk` will output

```
Created a new partition 2 of type 'Extended' and of size 99.8 GiB.
      image2 :       501758    209715199 (99.8G) Extended
```

For `image3`, enter simply

```
501760
```

`sfdisk` will then output

```
Created a new partition 5 of type 'Linux' and of size 99.8 GiB.
      image5 :       501760    209715199 (99.8G) Linux
```

and prompt for `image6`, which we don’t need, so enter

```
quit
```

which will cause `sfdisk` to print the new partition table and ask if you want to write it to disk:

```
New situation:

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
image1     *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
image2          501758 209715199 209213442 99.8G  5 Extended
image5          501760 209715199 209213440 99.8G 83 Linux

Do you want to write this to disk? [Y]es/[N]o:
```

If you’re convinced the starting sectors all match, and `sda1` is still OK, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to write the partition table and return to your shell.

Once that’s done, run

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
```

to resize your LVM PV; you should then be able to use the newly-allocated disk space (in new LVs, or to extend existing LVs).