# How to increase LVM partition

Tags: partition, lvm, fdisk, lsblk

I'm using RHEL7 and here is my partition:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0             2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda             8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   39G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0   35G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

As you can see, `rhel-root` is the root directory, whose size is 35G. The size of `sda` is 100G, which means that there is `(100 - 39 - 1)G = 60G` unused spaces.

How could I add the 60G spaces to the `sda2` to increase the size of root directory?

Output of `pvs`:

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  rhel lvm2 a--  <39.00g    0
```

Output of `vgs`:

```
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  rhel   1   2   0 wz--n- <39.00g    0
```

Output of `lvs`:

```
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root rhel -wi-ao---- <35.00g
  swap rhel -wi-ao----   4.00g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches.

The first, sticking closely to your suggestion, is to resize `sda2` to include the extra space:

- use your favourite partitioning tool to change the end sector of the partition (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379681/86440) for an example using `sfdisk` on an MBR-based partition table);
- run `pvresize /dev/sda2` to resize the PV.

This will make the extra space available in your VG, and you can then resize your LVs or create new LVs.

The second is to create a new partition:

- again using your favourite partitioning tool, create a third primary partition, `/dev/sda3`, with all the available space;
- run `pvcreate /dev/sda3` to initialise it as a PV;
- run `vgextend rhel /dev/sda3` to add the PV to your VG.

It should be possible to do all this without rebooting...